# xargs -I option

Tags: xargs

The [xargs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html#xargs-options) says :

> -I replace-str
>   --replace[=replace-str]
>   -i[replace-str]
>   Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial arguments with names read from standard input.

I don't understand this part: `with names read from standard input.`

For example what is happening with:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0I{} echo | wc -l
```

The above piece of code counts the total files/directories inside a directory.

Could anybody explain this for me?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

"with names read from standard input" means that `xargs` takes the data coming in on its standard input, splits it up, and uses it to run the command given in its arguments. By default, it splits on blanks or newlines, and runs `echo` with as many arguments at a time as possible.

The `-0` option in your example instructs `xargs` to split its input on null bytes instead of blanks or newlines. Combined with `find`'s `-print0`, this allows filenames containing blanks or newlines to be handled properly.

The `-I` option changes the way the new command lines are built. Instead of adding as many arguments as possible at a time, `xargs` will take one name at a time from its input, look for the given token (`{}` here) and replace that with the name.

In your example, `{}` isn't present in the command template given to `xargs`, so in effect `xargs` is instructed to run `echo` with no argument, once for every filename given to it by `find`. To see this, drop the `wc`:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0I{} echo
```

You'll see a series of blank lines... Compare this with

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0I{} echo {}
```

and

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 echo
```

and

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0
```

to get a better understanding.

Comment: Use a subshell if you want to exec 2 commands while using the interpolation param: `..|xargs -0I{} sh -c 'echo {} && echo {}'`.

Comment: @Alex that exposes you to incorrect behaviour depending on the characters in your file names; see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506266/86440) for a safer approach using `xargs` and `sh`.

Comment: Nice tip. For everyone who doesn't want to navigate away, in order to support single quotes and other strange chars in filenames use: `..| xargs -0I{} sh -c 'echo $1 && ..' sh {}`. The last `sh` is a dummy arg and can (but shouldn't really) be replaced with an arbitrary string.