# Use xargs to build and run a command list

Tags: xargs

How to use `xargs` to build and run a *command list* such as these:

```
#1
cmd1 <arg1> && cmd2 <arg1> && cmd3 <arg1>
#2
cmd1 <arg1> ; cmd2 <arg1>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By starting a child shell for each line of input to `xargs`:

```
xargs -I {} sh -c 'cmd1 "$1" && cmd2 "$1" && cmd3 "$1"' sh {}

xargs -I {} sh -c 'cmd1 "$1"; cmd2 "$1"' sh {}
```

This runs `sh -c` which executes the given string as a shell script.  The arguments to `sh -c`, after the script itself, are given to `$0` and `$1` inside the script.  The value of `$0` should usually be the name of the shell, which is why we pass `sh` as this argument (it will be used in error messages).

Alternatively,

```
xargs sh -c '
    for arg do
        cmd1 "$arg" && cmd2 "$arg" && cmd3 "$arg"
    done' sh

xargs sh -c '
    for arg do
        cmd1 "$arg"
        cmd2 "$arg"
    done' sh
```

These variations will take as many arguments as possible and then apply the code to these in a loop inside the `sh -c` scripts.

As always when using `xargs`, care must be taken so that the arguments supplied to the given utility (`sh -c` here) are delimited properly.

Comment: I'm actually using this method, but I wonder if there's any other ways that are more *xargs native*.

Comment: @TranTriet No, not really. This is a fairly common way of doing it. What are your issues with this way of doing it?

Comment: @TranTriet See updated answer.